# Is Youtube data Api v3 support batch processing

Tags: youtube, batch-processing, youtube-data-api

I want to use youtube api v3 to scrape video datas, and I wish to use batch processing to reduece the overhead.

Youtube api v2 seem support batch processing, but I cannot find how to use batch processing for youtube data api v3.

If it support, what's the batch URL, and can I use http post finish it without google api client liberary.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer to your question?